# Moq - Mock method returns null

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq

AddAsync method always returns null

Code where I mocked the data:

```
var mockFileService = new Mock<IFileService>();

var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is a dummy file");
IFormFile file = new FormFile(new MemoryStream(bytes), 0, bytes.Length, "Data", "dummy.pdf");

mockFileService.Setup(f => f.AddAsync(file, "pathToFolder", "nameFile")).ReturnsAsync("pathToFile");
_fileService = mockFileService.Object;
```

Interface which I mock:

```
public interface IFileService
{
    Task<string> AddAsync(IFormFile file, string pathToFolder, string nameFile);
    Task<string> AddAsync(byte[] file, string pathToFolder, string nameFile);
    Task AddImagesJpegAsync(Image[] images, string path, string imagesPrefix);
    Task<byte[]> GetAsync(string pathToFile);
    void DeleteFolder(string path);
    void CreateFolder(string path);
}
```

Comment: I think you should be specifying `It.IsAny<IFormFile>()` instead of using `file` in your setup. Possibly the same goes for the other two string params too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mock setup, you are saying this:

```
mockFileService.Setup(f => f.AddAsync(
    file, "pathToFolder", "nameFile"))....
```

This is saying that any time the `AddAsync` method is called on your mock with those exact parameter values, and for an object reference, it must also be that same object you just created. Instead, you should use the `It.AsAny` methods provided by Moq, for example:

```
mockFileService.Setup(f => f.AddAsync(
    It.AsAny<IFormFile>(), It.AsAny<string>(), It.AsAny<string>()))....
```